# Killing a Hydra - Overengineered

Tags: python, python-3.x, programming-challenge, recursion, dynamic-programming

#### Background

This question is inspired by the question: [Killing a hydra](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/263444/61495), and my response therein. I will restate the problem at hand in full so that this question is fully self contained

> You can only kill off a given number of heads at each hit and
> corresponding number of heads grow back. The heads will not grow back
> if the hydra is left with zero heads. For example:
>
> ```
> heads = [135] 
> hits = [25,67,1,62] 
> growths = [15,25,15,34]
> ```
>
> Then you can kill off `hits[i]` heads but `growths[i]` heads grow back.

The important restriction here is that:

> *you have to leave the Hydra with **exactly** zero heads to win*.

---

**My own restriction in this post is that I want to try to minimize the number of hits necessary to kill**

---

#### Algorithm

After some consideration I came up with the following strategy. **Note:** this strategy is *not* part of my answer on the original question.

1. The difficult part is leaving the Hydra with *exactly* zero heads. So in order to accomplish this I wrote a short code that generates all optimal ways to leave the Hydra 1 hit from death. This is used as a lookup table for small number of heads.

   - To create the lookup table fast, we create iterate over all possible `diffs` up to a certain magnitude. A `diff` is simply the change in heads after a hit and a regrow.
     We then create a dict of these `diffs`
     Each `diff` has multiple keys associated with them, which represents the number of heads reachable with 1 hit from that `diff`.

     **Example**

     ```
     hits = [1, 25, 62, 67]
     growths = [15, 15, 34, 25]       
     diff = [1, 4, 0, 0]
     ```

     This corresponds to the number `1 * (1 - 15) + 4 * (25 - 15) = 26`. Which means that after applying `diff` to the Hydra, the Hydra has `26` fewer heads remaining. This also means that a Hydra with `88` heads is dead after `diff` heads have been removed. Why? Because `88 - 26 = 67` and `67` is in hits. In other words we create a dict which looks like

     ```
     hydra_dict = {26+1: diff, 26+25: diff, 26+62: diff, 26+67: diff}
     ```
2. If our number of heads is greater than the largest value in our lookup dict,
   we remove
   values by picking the greatest `diff` and applying it `x` times to heads until we are in range. We overshoot a bit to make sure we are not at the very edge of our lookup dict.
3. If the number of heads lies in our `hydra_dict` we simply return this value.
4. Else we run a breadth first recursive search to either find a value in our dict, or a valid configuration of hits to kill the hydra.

---

##### Questions

I think I barely managed to make my code presentable, typing hints, using a class etc. However, my main issues is with the implementation

- How do I decide how big my lookup table should be? At the moment I just hardcoded that every `diff` can at most be `7`. I tried with a few lower values and a few higher, but not sure how I can properly find the best limit. *Do my diff limits have to be of same length*?
- How do I decide how deep my recursive algorithm should go? At the moment it is hardcoded to be the same value as the size of my lookup table, which works. However, for smaller lookup tables I seem to need to use a bigger depth. `10` seems to always return something proper, again not sure how to find the proper value.
- Instead of using a recursive solution I can "fill in the missing gaps" in my lookup table. This can be done by switching the switch`COMPLETE_HYDRA_DICT = False`. The benefits are that we always arrive at a lookup value after shaving off the too large values. The downside, is that it is resource heavy to fill in the table. Any thoughts?
- My recursive function returns the solution with the *minimal* sum. I tried writing a recursive function that returns the first solution instead. Is this better? From some rudimentary testing it appears that these two (the return first recursive, and return minimal sum recursive) returns mostly the same values with a big enough lookup table.
- Any other suggestions on improving the recursive function is welcome. I am not sure if it is possible to include any more early exits to speed up the code.

---

#### Code

```
import itertools
from typing import Union

Head, Hit, Growth = int, int, int
Heads, Hits, Growths = list[Head], list[Hit], list[Growth]
HitGrowthDiff = Union[Hit, Growth]
HitGrowthDiffs = list[HitGrowthDiff]
HydraDict = dict[Head, HitGrowthDiffs]

MAX_LOOKUP = 7
RECURSIVE_DEPTH = MAX_LOOKUP
COMPLETE_HYDRA_DICT = False


COUNT_ITERS = 0


class Hydra:
    """Tries to find the minimal required hits to kill the hydra"""

    def __init__(self, hits: Hits, growths: Growths, hydra_heads=0):
        self._hits = hits
        self._growths = growths
        self.update_variables()
        if hydra_heads > 0:
            self._heads = hydra_heads

    @property
    def hits(self) -> Hits:
        return self._hits

    @hits.setter
    def hits(self, hits):
        self._hits = hits
        self.update_variables()

    @property
    def growths(self) -> Growths:
        return self._growths

    @growths.setter
    def growths(self, growths):
        self._growths = growths
        self.update_variables()

    @property
    def diffs(self) -> HitGrowthDiffs:
        return self._diffs

    @diffs.setter
    def diffs(self, diffs):
        self._diffs = diffs
        self.update_variables()

    @property
    def head(self) -> Head:
        return self._head

    @head.setter
    def head(self, head):
        self._head = head
        self.diffs_2_kill(head)

    def update_variables(self) -> None:
        hits = [0] * len(self.hits)
        growths, diffs = hits.copy(), hits.copy()
        for index, (hit, growth) in enumerate(
            sorted(
                zip(self.hits, self.growths),
                key=lambda sub: sub[1] - sub[0],
                reverse=True,
            )
        ):
            hits[index], growths[index], diffs[index] = hit, growth, hit - growth

        self._hits, self._growths, self._diffs = hits, growths, diffs

        self.generate_diffs_2_kill_hydra_lookup()
        self.max_hydra = max(self.diffs_2_kill_)
        self.max_diff = max(self.diffs)
        self.max_diff_index = self.diffs.index(self.max_diff)

    def generate_diffs_2_kill_hydra_lookup(
        self,
        limit: int = MAX_LOOKUP,
        complete: bool = COMPLETE_HYDRA_DICT,
    ) -> None:
        """Generates a dictionary of optimal hit values for a large sample of heads"""
        self.diffs_2_kill_ = dict()
        for diffs_count in itertools.product(*[range(limit) for _ in self.diffs]):
            hits = sum(d * count for d, count in zip(self.diffs, diffs_count))
            if hits < 0:
                continue
            for final_hit in self.hits:
                total_hits = hits + final_hit
                if total_hits not in self.diffs_2_kill_:
                    self.diffs_2_kill_[total_hits] = list(diffs_count)
                elif sum(self.diffs_2_kill_[total_hits]) > sum(diffs_count):
                    self.diffs_2_kill_[total_hits] = list(diffs_count)

        if complete:
            self.complete_diffs_2_kill_hydra_lookup()

    def complete_diffs_2_kill_hydra_lookup(self) -> None:
        """Finds the missing head values in hydra_dict and fills them in manually"""
        unreachable = sorted(
            set(range(max(self.diffs_2_kill_) + 1)) - set(self.diffs_2_kill_.keys())
        )
        reachable_len = [0, 0]
        for head, next_head in zip(unreachable[:-1], unreachable[1:]):
            if next_head - head > reachable_len[1] - reachable_len[0]:
                reachable_len = [head, next_head]
        print(reachable_len)

        for head in range(1, reachable_len[0]):
            if head in self.diffs_2_kill_:
                continue
            self.diffs_2_kill_[head] = self.diffs_2_kill_iterative(head)
        self.diffs_2_kill_ = dict(
            [
                (head, kill)
                for head, kill in self.diffs_2_kill_.items()
                if head < reachable_len[1]
            ]
        )

    def heads_removed(self, number_of_hits: list[int]) -> Head:
        return sum(diff * number for diff, number in zip(self.diffs, number_of_hits))

    def is_hydra_one_hit_from_death(self, total_heads: Head, number_of_hits) -> bool:
        """Checks if Hydra is 1 hit away from death after n hits"""
        heads_left = total_heads - self.heads_removed(number_of_hits)
        return heads_left in self.hits

    def diffs_2_kill_iterative(
        self,
        head: Head,
        nums: int = MAX_LOOKUP,
    ) -> HitGrowthDiffs:
        """Iterates over all possible number of hits, returns first 1 hit from death"""
        for hydra_hits in itertools.product(*[range(nums) for _ in self.hits]):
            if self.is_hydra_one_hit_from_death(head, list(hydra_hits)):
                return list(hydra_hits)
        return []

    def diffs_2_kill(
        self,
        head: Head,
    ) -> None:
        """Low level function to check if a head is killable"""
        extra_hits = [0] * len(self.diffs)
        # Removes heads until we are in lookup range
        if head > self.max_hydra:
            times = int((head - self.max_hydra) / self.max_diff + 1)
            head -= times * self.max_diff
            extra_hits[self.max_diff_index] += times

        if head in self.diffs_2_kill_:
            final_hits = self.diffs_2_kill_[head]
        else:
            final_hits = self.diffs_2_kill_recursive(head)
        heads = list(hits + extra for hits, extra in zip(final_hits, extra_hits))
        self.final_hit = self.head - self.heads_removed(heads)
        self.number_of_diffs_2_kill = heads
        self.kill_hits = dict(zip(self.hits, self.number_of_diffs_2_kill))

    def diffs_2_kill_recursive(
        self,
        head: Head,
        diff: HitGrowthDiff = None,
        new_hits: Hits = None,
        diff_index: int = None,
        depth: int = RECURSIVE_DEPTH,
    ) -> HitGrowthDiffs:

        if new_hits is None:
            new_hits = [0] * len(self.diffs)
        if diff_index is not None:
            new_hits[diff_index] += 1
        if head == 0:
            return new_hits
        elif head in self.diffs_2_kill_:
            heads_ = [
                hit + extra for hit, extra in zip(self.diffs_2_kill_[head], new_hits)
            ]
            return heads_
        elif depth == 0:
            return []
        elif (diff is None) or (diff < head):
            final_diffs = [
                self.diffs_2_kill_recursive(
                    head - diff,
                    diff,
                    new_hits.copy(),
                    diff_index,
                    depth - 1,
                )
                for diff_index, diff in enumerate(self.diffs)
            ]
            return min(list(filter(None, final_diffs)), key=sum, default=[])
        return []

    def __str__(self):
        width = 60
        string = "=" * width + "\n"
        string += f"Hydra heads: {self.head}".center(width)
        string += "\n" + "=" * width

        head = self.head
        for index, number_of_hits in enumerate(self.number_of_diffs_2_kill):
            hit, growth = self.hits[index], self.growths[index]

            if number_of_hits < 6:
                for _ in range(number_of_hits):
                    string += f"\nWe kill {hit} heads of the hydra!"
                    string += f"\nOh no! {growth} heads regrew!"
                    head -= hit - growth
                    string += f"\n {head} heads remain!"
            else:
                string += f"\nWe kill {hit} heads of the hydra!"
                string += f"\nOh no! {growth} heads regrew!"
                head -= hit - growth
                string += f"\n {head} heads remain!"
                string += "\n      ." * 3
                string += f"\nThis is repeated {number_of_hits-2} times"
                string += "\n      ." * 3
                head -= (hit - growth) * (number_of_hits - 2)
                string += f"\nWe kill {hit} heads of the hydra!"
                string += f"\nOh no! {growth} heads regrew!"
                head -= hit - growth
                string += f"\n {head} heads remain!"

            string += "\n"
        string += f"\nWe kill {self.final_hit} heads of the hydra!"
        head -= self.final_hit
        if head == 0:
            string += "\n The Hydra is dead!"
        string += "\n" + "~" * width + "\n"
        return string


def main():

    heads = [88, 135, 192, 4321, 98767893]
    hits = [25, 67, 1, 62]
    growths = [15, 25, 15, 34]

    hydra = Hydra(hits, growths)
    for head in heads:
        hydra.head = head
        print(hydra)


if __name__ == "__main__":

    main()
```

Comment: Please always tag Python questions with [tag:python] so the correct syntax highlighter is used.

Comment: If N heads is 10, the program prints: "We kill 25 heads of the hydra! Oh no! 15 heads regrew! 0 heads remain!". That doesn't make sense to me (how does one hit/kill 25 heads when only 10 existed) and it seems contrary to the spirit of the challenge -- namely, to exactly kill the hydra. Have I misunderstood or is that a previously unknown bug?

Comment: @FMc *Unforseen bug, so sorry! I've worked a bit more on the code afterwards and the bug is fixed. I'll leave the question as is for now. But I probably will answer my own question in a week or two when things slow down at work. In the mean time feel free to answer the question if you want. (The code was, to the posters knowledge, working as intended when posted)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This was an interesting puzzle and your question was framed very well. I have a
few code-review style comments. Those are followed by some discussion of, and
corresponding code for, a different algorithmic approach -- one that seems
easier to follow, at least to my eye.

**The Hydra class has a complex implementation**. Its own internal state
requires fair bit of coordination, as evidenced primarily by the need to invoke
`self.update_variables()` in various setters. Sometimes such dependencies are
unavoidable, but one should generally view them as a potential warning sign. In this specific case,
I think the warning is worth heeding. I don't think the complexity in the class
is required.

**A small symptom of the complexity**. The Hydra class has bug. The API says
you can pass the N of `hydra_heads` as an argument: `Hydra(hits, growths, 2)`.
But if you do, `print(hydra)` fails because `_head` has not been set. The
culprit is this line in the initializer: `self._heads = hydra_heads`.
Superficially, there is a typo (it should be `self._head` rather than
`self._heads`). Of course, that mistake is natural because you have a plural
thing (N of heads) but your code gives it a singular name (hence the
confusion). But all of that is the surface layer. The deeper problem is that
the initializer must use the setter, so that the object keeps its internal
state aligned: `self.head = hydra_heads`.

**The Hydra class is over-eager**. A good guideline is to keep object
initialization simple and lightweight: store the parameters and await further
instruction. Your implementation solves the whole problem immediately. In my
experience, lightweight initialization is usually better for testability,
debuggability, and flexibility in the face of evolving requirements. But that's
just a guideline, and there can be valid exceptions. But notice that if we
decide to make `Hydra` eager during initialization, we could also decide to
design the class to discourage mutation by users of the class. In other words,
if the class solves the whole problem upon initialization, there's much less
need for a bunch of setters that carefully align internal state. Eager can
often be paired with a policy of treating the objects as non-modifiable, at
least in spirit.

**The Hydra class does not readily answer the primary question**. Your stated
goal is to *minimize the number of hits necessary to kill the hydra*. But the
class does not appear to have a simple way to answer that question: how many
hits were required? It also does not appear to have an easy way to see how many
hits of each kind were required. Maybe there is a way and I overlooked it. In
my case, I looked for a while and then just reverse-engineered the `__str__()`
method to get the information I wanted. During my early experimentation, I
added a few properties to your class to get what I needed.

**Make debugging code data-oriented, not print-oriented**. Your `__str__()`
method is basically a debugging tool -- or at least that's the only use I can
really see for it, and it's how I used it -- but a big string of narrative text
is not a good debugging mechanism. Much better is data: one or more
methods/properties to return the needed debugging facts. And even if you want
the debugging information to be converted to text for reading (for example, to
trace program logic), make the output data-oriented rather
than textual. The precise format can vary depending on the problem, but the key
is to emit the data in a way that is easy to scan and navigate visually.
Sometimes tabular presentations work well (e.g., to see changes running down
a column), sometimes hierarchy/indentation works well (e.g., to convey changes as
state evolves through the program logic), and there are other possibilities.
The main point is to be systematic and focus on the data. When experimenting
with this problem I ended up writing a little debug function to print
keyword-style data at various indentation levels mirroring the structure of my
algorithm:

```
def debug(level, label, **kws):
    if False:
        msg = '  ' * level + label + ':'
        for k, v in kws.items():
            msg += f' {k}={v}'
        print(msg)
```

**A simpler optimization**. A fair bit of your code is oriented toward creating
and managing optimizations like a lookup table. But one only needs optimization
for large scale, which in this problem means a large number of heads. But when
the N of heads is very large, the problem requires no optimization, because
there is only one move to make: select the `Hit` with the largest positive
difference between the N of heads removed vs regrown. Only when the numbers get
smaller do we have to fuss over `Hit` selection so that we exactly kill the
beast. To take advantage of those observations, we need a way to draw a line
between *very large* N of heads and everything else. Least common multiples
provide a convincing heuristic. In our case we have 4 `Hit` instances having
the following removed/regrown differences: -14, 10, 28, and 42. We can ignore
the negative value. The least common multiple of the other three differences is
420. If you need to remove significantly more than 420 heads, the most efficient
way to do it is with the big-hits: use 10 of the 42-diff `Hit` rather than 15
of the 28-diff `Hit`, for example. I picked a conservative heuristic: any heads
beyond 5x of that LCM were removed immediately by repeated applications of the
42-diff `Hit`. Since 5x the LCM is a tiny number, we don't really need to worry
about any further optimization.

**A `Hit` dataclass**. You have list of `hits` (heads removed) and a parallel
list of `growths` (heads regrown). I knew that I wanted to unify that data as a
single list of `Hit` data objects. It was also handy to give that object a
property for net head removal.

```
from dataclasses import dataclass

@dataclass(frozen = True)
class Hit:
    removed: int
    regrown: int

    @property
    def net_removed(self):
        return self.removed - self.regrown
```

**A stack-based DFS algorithm, with guiding restrictions**. I also expected
that my no-need-for-optimization algorithm could be a stack-based DFS search --
but one arranged to find the optimal solution first. That is achieved through
the interplay between two features of the algorithm. First, it tries bigger
`Hit` instances before smaller, because we want the most efficient kill.
Second, and pulling in the opposite direction, it requires that the `Hit`
instances be selected in a monotonically increasing fashion. In other words, we
might prefer to use bigger hits, but selecting bigger hits comes with a cost:
smaller hits are disallowed on all subsequent selections. On a "representative"
DFS traversal, the algorithm naively starts with big selections, but those
reach a dead end if the solution requires some smaller hits too. The pathways
involving smaller hits are put into the stack, so we will eventually explore
them and find a solution. But, again, on any specific selection, the algorithm
prefers the biggest allowed hit, which ensures that we will choose the fewest
small hits possible when reaching the solution. That's an intuitive explanation
for the logic. I think one could make a formal proof that these two features
produce a correct solution, but I basically convinced myself that they worked
through old-fashioned experimentation. As always, I might be wrong.

**A `State` dataclass**. To simplify information management within stack or
queue based algorithms, it often helps to use a data object to represent
program state. Here's what I ended up with:

```
@dataclass
class State:
    n_heads: int     # N heads remaining.
    counts: list     # Counts of Hits delivered so far.
    rng: range       # Indexes of remaining candidate Hits.

    def __post_init__(self):
        # Ensure that each State gets an independent list of counts.
        self.counts = list(self.counts)
```

**Orchestration code**. My own code evolved as I experimented toward a
solution, but here's a simplified setup:

```
import sys

def main(args):
    hits = [Hit(25, 15), Hit(67, 25), Hit(1, 15), Hit(62, 34)]
    n_heads = int(args[0])
    counts = hits_to_kill_hydra(n_heads, hits)
    print(n_heads, counts)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main(sys.argv[1:])
```

**Algorithm**. And the algorithm ended up in one main function with two small
helpers. If one were feeling object-oriented, this code could be wrapped in a
`HydraKiller` class or something, but I'm not convinced that would help too
much with clarity. It might help if one had other goals or reporting needs in
mind. I got interested in the puzzle mainly from the perspective of trying to
write a solution that was as simple and intuitive as possible.

```
import math

def hits_to_kill_hydra(n_heads, hits):
    # Sort hits from small to large.
    hits = sorted(hits, key = lambda h: h.net_removed)

    # Set up initial n_heads and counts after quickly
    # removing any heads beyond the LCM-based threshold.
    n_heads, counts = rapid_head_removal(n_heads, hits)

    # Initialize stack with the starting State.
    limit = len(hits)
    s = State(n_heads, counts, range(0, limit))
    stack = [s]

    while stack:

        # Get current State.
        s = stack.pop()

        # Return a dict mapping hits to counts if we
        # can kill the hydra on the next Hit.
        i = immediate_kill(s.n_heads, hits)
        if i is not None:
            s.counts[i] += 1
            return dict(zip(hits, s.counts))

        # Otherwise, select the largest legal hit among those
        # specified by the current range of indexes.
        for i in reversed(s.rng):
            h = hits[i]
            if h.removed < s.n_heads:
                # In case hits[i] leads to a dead end, we need to put the
                # not-yet-considered alternatives (ie, Hits smaller than the
                # selected one) into the stack for later backtracking.
                if i > s.rng.start:
                    s2 = State(s.n_heads, s.counts, range(s.rng.start, i))
                    stack.append(s2)

                # Adjust state information based on selecting hits[i]. The
                # adjustments for n_heads and counts are straightforward. The
                # key part is the next State.rng: it ensures the the Hits will
                # be selected in a monotonically increasing fashion.
                s.counts[i] += 1
                n2 = s.n_heads - h.net_removed
                s2 = State(n2, s.counts, range(i, limit))
                stack.append(s2)
                break

    return None

def rapid_head_removal(n_heads, hits):
    # Compute N of heads beyond the 5x LCM threshold.
    net_removals = [h.net_removed for h in hits if h.net_removed > 0]
    surplus = n_heads - 5 * math.lcm(*net_removals)

    # Compute N of the biggest Hit to apply.
    big_hit = hits[-1]
    n_big = surplus // big_hit.net_removed

    # Use n_big to return the adjusted n_heads and counts.
    counts = [0 for _ in hits]
    if n_big > 0:
        counts[-1] += n_big
        n_heads -= n_big * big_hit.net_removed
    return (n_heads, counts)

def immediate_kill(n_heads, hits):
    # Return index of Hit that would immediately kill the hydra.
    for i, h in enumerate(hits):
        if n_heads == h.removed:
            return i
    return None
```

Comment: Fantastic answer! I might use this as a baseline to ask a follow up question implementing your suggestions. I 100% agree with you. My only question is how do you, from a hit list figure out what the final hit was? If the hits is applied randomly the hydra might be left with a negative number of heads. This is why I focused on the number of ways to leave the Hydra 1 hit away from death.

Comment: @N3buchadnezzar  The final is the biggest, due to the algorithm. But even with a different algorithm, one can derive it from the counts. Consider `n_heads=3`, which has solution `(3, 3, 0, 0)`. Total up the net removals to get -12. Subtract initial `n_heads` to get -15. The final hit is the one with a matching (positive) value for regrown. BTW, I was reminded that my function's return value isn't great because it returns the counts in order of the sorted hits. A better return would be `dict(zip(hits, s.counts))` so the user would not have to know about algorithm internals (edited accordingly).